# Cannot get list to be loaded in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue trying to get the list view loaded. Here is the sample code that I'm using to load the list view. The SearchFragment calls the adaptor to load the data. The MainActivity calls the SearchFragment. The list doesn't get populated with the data.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_text"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"/>-->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
            android:name="fragments.SearchFragment"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="4px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

search_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:orientation="horizontal">
    <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:queryHint="Search here"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package sample

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.TextView
import fragments.SearchFragment

actual class Sample {
    actual fun checkMe() = 44
}

actual object Platform {
    actual val name: String = "Android"
}

class MainActivity :  AppCompatActivity()  {

    lateinit var searchFragment: SearchFragment

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //findViewById<TextView>(R.id.main_text).text = hello()
        //setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
       this.searchFragment = SearchFragment()
       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.details_fragment, searchFragment)
           .addToBackStack(searchFragment.toString())
           .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
           .commit()

   }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        return true
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            true
        }

        else -> {
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

}
```

SearchFragment.kt

```
package fragments

import adaptors.SearchAdaptor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.SearchView
import objects.Search
import sample.R

class SearchFragment : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.searchlayout,
            container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val search = Search("yer", "50")
        val search1 = Search("ter", "60")
        val search2 = Search("yer", "50")
        val search3 = Search("ter", "60")
        val search4= Search("yer", "50")
        val search5 = Search("ter", "60")
        val list = arrayListOf(search, search1, search2, search3, search4, search5)
        val adaptor = SearchAdaptor(activity, R.layout.rowlayout, list)

        val listView: ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_view)
        listView.adapter = adaptor

    }
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

SearchAdaptor.kt

```
package adaptors
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import objects.Search
import sample.R


class SearchAdaptor(context: Context?, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<Search>) : ArrayAdapter<Search>(context, resource, list)
{
    var resource: Int
    var list: ArrayList<Search>

    init {
        this.resource = resource
        this.list = list
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return this.list.size;
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
        var holder: ViewHolder
        var retView: View

        if(convertView == null){
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false)
            holder = ViewHolder()

            holder.image = retView.findViewById(R.id.icon) as ImageView?
            holder.text = retView.findViewById(R.id.label) as TextView?
            retView.tag = holder

        } else {
            holder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
            retView = convertView
        }

        val attraction = getItem(position)
        holder.text!!.text = attraction.cost
        return retView
    }


    internal class ViewHolder {
        var image: ImageView? = null
        var text: TextView? = null
    }

}
```

Here is the Logcat details

```
2019-08-06 13:25:37.831 2895-2895/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-08-06 13:25:38.015 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android W/ActivityThread: Application org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
2019-08-06 13:25:38.024 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
2019-08-06 13:25:39.072 2895-2904/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/zygote: Debugger is active
2019-08-06 13:25:39.232 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: Debugger has connected
2019-08-06 13:25:39.232 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:39.433 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:39.635 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:39.835 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:40.043 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:40.244 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:40.444 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:40.646 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:40.847 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-08-06 13:25:41.048 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/System.out: debugger has settled (1440)
2019-08-06 13:25:41.398 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-08-06 13:26:14.310 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-08-06 13:26:14.339 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-08-06 13:26:14.340 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-08-06 13:26:14.340 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-08-06 13:26:14.340 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-08-06 13:26:14.340 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-08-06 13:26:14.351 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xea3052a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-08-06 13:26:14.359 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea3052a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xea3033e0)
2019-08-06 13:26:17.305 2895-2895/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android I/Choreographer: Skipped 178 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-08-06 13:26:17.322 2895-3980/org.jetbrains.kotlin.mpp_app_android D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea3052a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xea3033e0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out there wasn't anything wrong with the code. It was an issue with how the layout was structured. Here are the final layout xml files.

search_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                             android:orientation="horizontal">
    <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:queryHint="Search here"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="4px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_text"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"/>-->

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell what exactly the issue that you are getting.

Also try changing to following :

in row_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                         android:orientation="horizontal">
```

in search_layout.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
/>
```

also post your logcat response along with what exactly is the issue

Comment: The listview doesn't populate with data